# How do I authenticate my Java application with Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, cygwin, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud-java

I am writing a Java application to interact with files in Google Cloud Storage. I found [`gcloud-java`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java) which I'm trying to get working.

Looking at their [examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/tree/master/gcloud-java-examples) it seems I should be able to simply run them after having logged-in with `gcloud`, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to run [`StorageExample`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.1.4/apidocs/com/google/gcloud/examples/storage/StorageExample.html), which says "*logged-in project will be used if not supplied*", but despite logging in I cannot access my project whether I specify it or not.

```
$ gcloud auth login
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?....


Saved Application Default Credentials.

You are now logged in as [...].
Your current project is [...].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID

$ java -cp GCloudDemo.jar com.google.gcloud.examples.storage.StorageExample list
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment.  Please set a project ID using the builder.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
        at com.google.gcloud.ServiceOptions.<init>(ServiceOptions.java:317)
        ...
        at com.google.gcloud.examples.storage.StorageExample.main(StorageExample.java:566)

$ java -cp GCloudDemo.jar com.google.gcloud.examples.storage.StorageExample ... list
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gcloud.storage.StorageException: Login Required
        at com.google.gcloud.spi.DefaultStorageRpc.translate(DefaultStorageRpc.java:94)
        at com.google.gcloud.spi.DefaultStorageRpc.list(DefaultStorageRpc.java:148)
        ...
        at com.google.gcloud.examples.storage.StorageExample$ListAction.run(StorageExample.java:1)
        at com.google.gcloud.examples.storage.StorageExample.main(StorageExample.java:579)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Login Required",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Login Required"
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
        ...
        at com.google.gcloud.spi.DefaultStorageRpc.list(DefaultStorageRpc.java:138)
        ... 10 more
```

Clearly something is wrong with my environment, but what do I have to do to fix it? I'd like to correct my environment rather than make changes to the example.

Notes:

- I'm running in Cygwin 2.0.4 on Windows 10
- I'm not building via Maven, but I *assume* that isn't the source of the problem

Comment: As an update, I had a much easier time getting things working with [WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl) than with Cygwin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `gcloud auth login` isn't working is because Java doesn't play well with Cygwin, specifically with regards to absolute paths.

`gcloud` stores your settings and credentials in your Cygwin home directory, `~/.config/gcloud`, but Java is going to look for them in your *Windows* home directory via [`System.getProperty("user.home")`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/blob/master/gcloud-java-core/src/main/java/com/google/gcloud/ServiceOptions.java#L384). You can specify where the application should look for this directory via the `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` environment variable, like so (be sure to only specify it when calling `java`; setting it for your shell will in turn break `gcloud`):

```
$ CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=$(cygpath -w ~/.config/gcloud) \
  java -cp GCloudDemo.jar com.google.gcloud.examples.storage.StorageExample list 
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gcloud.storage.StorageException: Login Required
    at ....
```

Notice that that we didn't have to specify a project, but we're still not logged in for some reason. It turns out the demo app doesn't do a great job of reporting authentication errors. Adding an explicit call to `AuthCredentials.createApplicationDefaults()` at the start of the `main()` method reports a much more helpful error message:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are
> not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the
> environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a
> file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
> for more information.
> ```

So now we at least have the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to go on. But why isn't `gcloud` configuring things for us? It looks like that's actually a [bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/issues/680) in the library; it *should* now be able to find our login token.

In the meantime, we can workaround it by explicitly specifying the credentials path as well:

```
$ CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=$(cygpath -w ~/.config/gcloud) \
  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$(cygpath -w ~/.config/gcloud)/application_default_credentials.json \
  java -cp GCloudDemo.jar com.google.gcloud.examples.storage.StorageExample list
Bucket{name=...}
```

Success!